# Java programming, currency calculator

Tags: java

As a beginner, i cannot really understand the issue in this code:

```
package Currency;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Currency {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double value1 = 0.00, value2 = 0.00;
        String currency;

        System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
        value1 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("USD or EUR: ");
        currency = input.nextLine();


        if(currency.equals("USD")){
            value2 = value1 * 0.734878047;
            System.out.println(value1 + "USD = " + value2 + " EUR. (Conversion rate: 1 USD = 0.734878047 EUR)");
        } else if (currency.equals("EUR")) {
            value2 = value1 * 1.36077;
            System.out.println(value1 + "EUR = " + value2 + " USD. (Conversion rate: 1 EUR = 1.36077 USD)");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Conversion rate: 1 USD = 0.734878047 EUR"
            + "\nConversion rate: 1 EUR = 1.36077 USD");
        }

        input.close();

    }

}
```

Somehow, it doesnt even read the second input, but just prints last else. Can anyone help me to get this right? :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you passing the input? Value and currency on 1 line?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `input.nextLine();` is reading in the newline from when the user hits enter after the first prompt.

A quick fix could be adding in another `input.nextLine()` "dummy" call before you prompt for `USD` or `EUR`:

```
package Currency;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Currency {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double value1 = 0.00, value2 = 0.00;
        String currency;

        System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
        value1 = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("USD or EUR: ");
        currency = input.nextLine();

        if(currency.equals("USD")){
            value2 = value1 * 0.734878047;
            System.out.println(value1 + "USD = " + value2 + " EUR. (Conversion rate: 1 USD = 0.734878047 EUR)");
        } else if (currency.equals("EUR")) {
            value2 = value1 * 1.36077;
            System.out.println(value1 + "EUR = " + value2 + " USD. (Conversion rate: 1 EUR = 1.36077 USD)");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Conversion rate: 1 USD = 0.734878047 EUR"
                    + "\nConversion rate: 1 EUR = 1.36077 USD");
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that hitting the return key is somewhat affecting the next readline. Doing a minor change as below seems to have fixed the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double value1 = 0.00, value2 = 0.00;
    String currency;

    System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
    String str = input.nextLine();
    value1 = Double.parseDouble(str);
    System.out.print("USD or EUR: ");
    currency = input.nextLine();


    if(currency.equals("USD")){
        value2 = value1 * 0.734878047;
        System.out.println(value1 + "USD = " + value2 + " EUR. (Conversion rate: 1 USD = 0.734878047 EUR)");
    } else if (currency.equals("EUR")) {
        value2 = value1 * 1.36077;
        System.out.println(value1 + "EUR = " + value2 + " USD. (Conversion rate: 1 EUR = 1.36077 USD)");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Conversion rate: 1 USD = 0.734878047 EUR"
        + "\nConversion rate: 1 EUR = 1.36077 USD");
    }

    input.close();
}
```

Example:

```
Enter a value: 25
USD or EUR: USD
25.0USD = 18.371951175 EUR. (Conversion rate: 1 USD = 0.734878047 EUR)
```

Alternatively, since in your case you are expecting a string without any white space, you could use the `.next()` property instead and leave your code as is:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double value1 = 0.00, value2 = 0.00;
    String currency;

    System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
    value1 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("USD or EUR: ");
    currency = input.next();


    if(currency.equals("USD")){
        value2 = value1 * 0.734878047;
        System.out.println(value1 + "USD = " + value2 + " EUR. (Conversion rate: 1 USD = 0.734878047 EUR)");
    } else if (currency.equals("EUR")) {
        value2 = value1 * 1.36077;
        System.out.println(value1 + "EUR = " + value2 + " USD. (Conversion rate: 1 EUR = 1.36077 USD)");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Conversion rate: 1 USD = 0.734878047 EUR"
        + "\nConversion rate: 1 EUR = 1.36077 USD");
    }

    input.close();

}
```

Answer (score -2):

in the `if` clauses in both cases use `currency.trim().equals(...` to remove any whitespaces at the beginning or end of the String.